# Can WiFi be turned on without user interaction?

Tags: wi-fi, networking

If my phone's WiFI is off, can it be turned in without me doing anything?

EDIT: Using Stock Samsung Android on a Samsung Galaxy Tab E.

Comment: An app with permission "[android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html)" can toggle the Wi-Fi. If there is an app with root access, it can also do so without requiring that permission.

Answer (score -1):

No. Without you do anything there's no way to do it.

Comment: Ever heard about phone profiles? Come built-in on some devices/ROMs. So your answer might be a bit too generic :)

Comment: @Izzy, generally though without something else installed his answer remains truue right?

Comment: @NateD On several phones, there's a profile manager pre-installed. I know that for sure if a device comes with CyanogenOS (as my Wileyfox Swift), and vaguely remember it from some Huawei devices – so there're probably more where no additional install is required (which is why I asked you to add your device and Android version – Samsung is a manufacturer, not a device ;). But sure, "without me doing *anything"* won't work, those profiles must at least be activated ;)